# How can we use "Decode" functionality in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, ios4

I would like to use "Decode" functionality in SQLite select statement.

From what I have read, it looks like there is no such function in SQLite.

What could be a workaround so that we use something similar to "Decode" in SQLite?

Comment: Found this thru google: http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=38

Comment: You might get better answers if you explain what you want to do rather than name a function that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no decode in Sqlite. Use "case statement instead" it's standard SQL an runs on any DB - which is better anyway.