# SQL Server IIF vs CASE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case, iif

I recently came to know about the availability of `IIF` function in SQL Server 2012. I always use nested `CASE` in my queries. I want to know the exact purpose of the `IIF` statement and when should we prefer using `IIF` over `CASE` Statement in the query.
I mostly use nested `CASE` in my queries.

Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: IIF is just a shorthand for a simple CASE statement. It is even translated into a case statement for query optimization and execution: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: It's a shame the shorthand isn't part of the standard (what is it these days? ANSISQL?) as it's much easier to read. But then T-SQL has always been a bit..."wordy".

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`IIF` is the same as `CASE WHEN <Condition> THEN <true part> ELSE <false part> END`. The query plan will be the same. It is, perhaps, "syntactical sugar" as initially implemented.

CASE is portable across all SQL platforms whereas IIF is SQL SERVER 2012+ specific.

Comment: Probably to make it easier on Access/VB developers to remember the syntax.

Answer (score 26):

IIF is a non-standard T-SQL function. It was added to SQL SERVER 2012, so that Access could migrate to SQL Server without refactoring the IIF's to CASE before hand. Once the Access db is fully migrated into SQL Server, you can refactor.

Comment: I like your reasoning. Can you support it by citing some documentation?

Comment: why would this answer require references and the other not? That's anonymous user discrimination :D