# mssql which is the syntax 'if'

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I have this code in mssql:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t2.Id,
    t1.QuantityIn,
    t1.PriceIn,
    t2.QuantityOut,

    (If (t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn)=0

        THEN t2.QuantityOut

    Else t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn ) AS Quant,

    t2.PriceOut

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
```

In software MsSql Server Management Studio error is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'If'.

What is the correct syntax for 'if' in my case?

Thank you!

Comment: @lad2025's answer is correct for SQL Server 2012+, but it is more portable to use a `CASE` statement.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839537/2084315

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) (SQL Server 2012 and above):

> IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t2.Id,
    t1.QuantityIn,
    t1.PriceIn,
    t2.QuantityOut,
    IIF (t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn=0,t2.QuantityOut
        , t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn ) AS Quant,
    t2.PriceOut
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
```

Comment: IIF you have SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t2.Id,
    t1.QuantityIn,
    t1.PriceIn,
    t2.QuantityOut,

    CASE WHEN t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn =0

        THEN t2.QuantityOut

    Else t2.QuantityOut - t1.QuantityIn END AS Quant,

    t2.PriceOut

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id
```